# What is the best method to rank elements with multiple attributes

Tags: ranking, rating

[image]

This is Kumar, the fire beast monk. The left numbers are the base stats, the green numbers are the stats provided by the equip runes. Depending on your runes you can make your monster more stronger.

- First four attributes are: Hit Points, Attack, Defense, Speed.
- The other four are: Critical Rate, Critical Damage, Resistance, Accuracy (those already have the runes stats add it)

I need a method to rank all the Kumars in my clan to see which one is the best so others can set a goal of improvement.

I have been thinking on 2 methods.

**Method 1:** For each attribute give points to the max value on that attribute and 1 point less to following in decreasing order. In this example I have the stats of 3 Kumars.

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
|            |  K1   |  K2   |  K3   |  MIN  |  MAX  | K1 | K2 | K3 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
| HP         | 44987 | 43831 | 40158 | 40158 | 44987 |  3 |  2 |  1 |
| ATK        |   804 |   753 |   846 |   753 |   846 |  2 |  1 |  3 |
| DEF        |   924 |   987 |   949 |   924 |   987 |  1 |  3 |  2 |
| SPD        |   105 |   163 |   162 |   105 |   163 |  1 |  3 |  2 |
| CRIT Rate  |    58 |   100 |    48 |    48 |   100 |  2 |  3 |  1 |
| CRIT Dmg   |    66 |   146 |    56 |    56 |   146 |  2 |  3 |  1 |
| Resistance |    21 |    22 |    40 |    21 |    40 |  1 |  2 |  3 |
| Accuracy   |    34 |    12 |    46 |    12 |    46 |  2 |  1 |  3 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
|            |       |       |       |       |       | 14 | 18 | 16 |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----+----+----+
```

For the attribute HP, K1 has the more HP there for get 3 points (because are 3 Kumars) , K2 is the next and get 2 points, K1 is the last and get 1 point.

There is also the option to assign point like they do in Formula 1 or MotoGp, Where first place get 25 points, second place get 20, then 15, 12, 10, 9, 8 ....

**Method 2**: Normalize each attribute to 0-1 value

```
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|            |  K1   |  K2   |  K3   |  MIN  |  MAX  |    K1    |    K2    |    K3    |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
| HP         | 44987 | 43831 | 40158 | 40158 | 44987 |  1.00    |  0.76    |  -       |
| ATK        |   804 |   753 |   846 |   753 |   846 |  0.55    |  -       |  1.00    |
| DEF        |   924 |   987 |   949 |   924 |   987 |  -       |  1.00    |  0.40    |
| SPD        |   105 |   163 |   162 |   105 |   163 |  -       |  1.00    |  0.98    |
| CRIT Rate  |    58 |   100 |    48 |    48 |   100 |  0.19    |  1.00    |  -       |
| CRIT Dmg   |    66 |   146 |    56 |    56 |   146 |  0.11    |  1.00    |  -       |
| Resistance |    21 |    22 |    40 |    21 |    40 |  -       |  0.05    |  1.00    |
| Accuracy   |    34 |    12 |    46 |    12 |    46 |  0.65    |  -       |  1.00    |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
|            |       |       |       |       |       |  2.50    |  4.81    |  4.38    |
+------------+-------+-------+-------+-------+-------+----------+----------+----------+
```

In not a mathematician, but I wise enough to not try invent the wheel again. So Im wondering if any of those methods is appropriate to rank an element with multiple attributes or if there is another method I should consider.

Right now Im considering Method 2. Because in Method 1 K3 seen as close to K1 as to K2. But in Method 2 you can see K2 and K3 are very similar but K1 is far behind.

Comment: If anyone think another tag would be relevant please let me know or add it.

Comment: Do you have data somewhere that has some measure of how good each fire lion monk dude is at ass-kicking or general fire-monkery?  If you did, you could see which attributes are most predictive of that, and do a weighted average.

Comment: @generic_user I have think about that. But the thing is there are 300 different monster, and are 5 elements for each one (water, fire, wind, dark, light) so would be very difficult (and subjective) set a parameter for each one. Also even with in same monster element some do different setup. For example Kumar is usually a `Tank` monster so require high HP,  but `K2`  give 100% crit rate so also can do damage.

Comment: If you have outcome data, it can be made into a regression problem, which is stiull subjective in some ways, but much more objective.

Comment: @generic_user what mean "outcome" data? I have the data of everyone on the clan.

Comment: Some measure of how good they are.  Number of people they eat, or whatever.  Call it $y$ and call all the attributes $\mathbf{X}$, then estimate $y = f(\mathbf{X})$